# Leaflet popup update closeOnClick

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map, I would like to change closeOnClick property of a popup after it is opened. I have tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
// at build
var mapPopupOptions = {maxWidth:600,minWidth:300};
var popup = new L.popup(mapPopupOptions).setContent("hello world");

// elsewhere after popup is open
popup.options.closeOnClick = false;
```

For reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup

Comment: what do you mean by ' it doesn't work' ? do you get any error ?

Comment: I am able to initially pass the closeOnClick option in the mapPopupOptions, and everything works ok.  I would like to be able to optionally "lock" the popup so that clicking on the map doesn't close it.  If I try to manually set the popup.options after the popup is created and displayed on the map, i cannot change this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I have just found a solution.
It does not matter whether you are getting the `popup` object from the marker using `getPopup()` or directly from a previous declaration.

For some reasons, the `update()` method does not work properly since it only updates the popup's aspect (`className`, `offset`, `minWidth`...) but not `options`' attributes relative to the popup's behavior.

Leaflet's popup's behavior (such as `closeOnClick` or `autoClose`) can be updated by re-initializing the popup's layout with the `_initLayout()` method.

For example in this case:

```js
// Once the popup has been created and/or opened
popup.options.closeOnClick = false;
popup._initLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing your initial Popup from that `popup` var, get the actual Popup reference from the Marker itself.

```
 // elsewhere after the popup is open
 var marker = // This is the marker are attempting to modify popup behavior
 var popup = marker.getPopup();
 // Modify the popup now
 popup.setContent("This popup has changed!", { closeOnClick: false });
```

It's likely that the `popup` object you are referencing is not the actual popup object that is being used by the marker you are modifying.

Comment: I tried your answer, unfortunately it didn't work, the content was set correctly, but the closeOnclick option remained unchanged